Jetpack Compose imePadding does not provide uniform padding and leads to glitchy keyboard behavior
The best way to describe the problem would be a video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ZY5zIaK82g
The video was recorded on an Android 13 phone, the same behavior was on the phone and emulator with Android 14.
In the video above you can see that the keyboard and indentation behave strangely, namely: The indentation is often slightly less than the height of the keyboard; Sometimes the indentation remains in place even after closing the keyboard; Sometimes after opening the keyboard the padding remains very small at the bottom of the screen; And almost always the keyboard flashes again after closing, and only then closes.
My code:
MainActivity.kt:
package com.samp.gui

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Spacer
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.WindowInsets
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.ime
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.imePadding
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.windowInsetsBottomHeight
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyColumn
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.rememberLazyListState
import androidx.compose.material3.TextField
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView
import androidx.core.view.WindowCompat
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsControllerCompat

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()

        val windowInsetsController =
            WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, window.decorView)
        windowInsetsController.systemBarsBehavior =
            WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
        windowInsetsController.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())

        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)

        val composeView = ComposeView(this)

        setContentView(composeView)

        composeView.setContent {
            val scrollState = rememberLazyListState()

            LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(Color.Red)
                    .fillMaxSize(),
                state = scrollState
            ) {
                item {
                    Column(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillParentMaxSize()
                            .background(Color.Green)
                    ) {
                        Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                            var text by remember {
                                mutableStateOf("")
                            }

                            TextField(
                                modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.TopCenter),
                                value = text,
                                onValueChange = { text = it },
                                singleLine = true
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
                item {
                    Spacer(Modifier.imePadding())
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

The reason I use AppCompatActivity is because the main application is migrating to compose. The reason to use LazyColumn would be to have fillParentMaxSize, without which the components inside will not fill the entire screen.
AndroidManifest.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Gui"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Gui"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

themes.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.Gui" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item>
    </style>
</resources>

Besides imePadding I tested ViewCompat.getRootWindowInsets(view).getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime()) and Modifier.windowInsetsBottomHeight(WindowInsets.ime) both worked the same as imePadding on video


The reason to use LazyColumn would be to have fillParentMaxSize, without which the components inside will not fill the entire screen.

You probably should not be using a LazyColumn in your case. The fillParentMaxSize() Modifier is there so you can make the each item of a LazyColumn be as big as the size of the LazyColumn. It does not make sense to use a LazyColumn just to have this Modifier.
You haven't specified what your UI should look like, but in case you just want to display a TextField and make sure that the keyboard does not overlap it, please use the fillMaxSize() Modifier as you already did and try the code below:
composeView.setContent {

    var text by remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
           .fillMaxSize()
           .imePadding(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Start
    ) {

        TextField(
            value = text,
            onValueChange = { text = it },
            singleLine = true
        )

    }
}

This should result in the same layout as you have with your current code. The keyboard will never overlap the TextField.
If you want to further customize the layout (horizontal alignment, vertical arrangement, check out the official documentation of Column.

This app is just a striped down version of my main app, where i need to have whole app scrollable. So this is not the answer. Fillmaxsize will not fill whole screen, but only the part above keyboard, making layout of app squeezed.
